# onRestore fails inside the bs4Dash, any workarounds?

Tags: r, shiny

It simply doesnt remember the text value, this is a simple reprex for my real problem with a complex app

```
library(bs4Dash)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(
    textInput("text", "Enter some text:"),
    bookmarkButton()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  onRestore(function(state) {
    updateTextInput(session, "text", value = state$input$text)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have turned off warnings because if you run your reprex, enter something in the text box then copy the provided url to a new tab you will get this on your console:

> Warning in force(expr) :
> Trying to restore saved app state, but UI code must be a function for this
> to work! See ?enableBookmarking

From the example provided at `?enableBookmarking`, this is how you should define your UI:

```r
ui <- function(req) {
  dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      textInput("text", "Enter some text:"),
      bookmarkButton()
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: Okay that does solve the reprex, my problem is with a module with OnRestore inside

Comment: Then your question was unclear. It didn't mention anything to do with modules, even on the reprex. You can add an edit with clarification below the original question or ask a new one explaining exactly what you need help with.